# ORDER BY with Case-Statement DESC

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-order-by

- How to `ORDER BY` with a `CASE`-Statement

  - first group:  null values in date-column `Col1` sorted by date-column `Col2 DESC`
  - second group: not-null values in date-column-`Col1` sorted by `Col1 DESC`

I've tried following:

```
SELECT columns FROM tables WHERE condition
ORDER BY 
    case when Table1.Col1 IS NULL     then 0 end, Table2.Col2 DESC,
    case when Table1.Col1 IS NOT NULL then 1 end, Table1.Col1 DESC
```

But the sort order is wrong, the NOT NULL values are first(sorted by Col2 instead of Col1). I think i've missed a detail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT columns FROM tables 
WHERE condition 
ORDER BY      
   case when Table1.Col1 IS NULL then 0 else 1 end ASC      
   ,case when Table1.Col1 IS NULL then Table2.Col2 else Table1.Col1 end DESC
```

Comment: `if(Cond,TrueVal,FalseVal)` would be more readable here than using `case when Cond then TrueVal else FalseVal end`

Answer (score 4):

This should work - just make the first column 0 or 1 based on whether it's null or not:

```
SELECT columns FROM tables WHERE condition
ORDER BY 
    case 
        when Table1.Col1 IS NULL     then 0 
                                     else 1
    end,
    case
        when Table1.Col1 IS NULL     then Table1.Col2
                                     else Table1.Col1
    end
```

Comment: Thanks, now the null-values are in front but the not-null values are not ordered by `Col1 desc` but `Col2 desc`.

Comment: just fixed - sorry, I misunderstood the requirement at first look